# Webpack and Karma Testing: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined using

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, karma-runner

I am having a weird issue with this library. I have set up my webpack to have an externals

```
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
```

this causes an error when i run `npm test` removing it allows my tests to run through karma correctly. However if i remove it, it doesn't allow me to run my foundation in my app.jsx

```
require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css')
$('document').foundation(); //This is where it errors
```

So if i remove the jquery external i get an error when i render at that point. If i add the externals jquery: 'jQuery' it breaks the testing. Anyone have any idea how to fix it. jQuery is part of my npm modules.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Then require `jquery` directly in your module:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css');
$('document').foundation();
```

Comment: tried that and it catches an error on the `$('document').foundation();` line

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact error, after trying a lot of things and rewrite the config files. I don't why, but this works.

Remove the externals
Change the plugin for:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
```

Results:

Test File

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var expect = require('expect');
var $ = require('jquery');
var TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');

var Clock = require('Clock');

describe('Clock', () => {
    it ('should exist', () => {
        expect(Clock).toExist();
    });
    describe('rebder', () => {
        it('should render clock to output', () => {
            var clock = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Clock totalSeconds={62}/>);
            var $el = $(ReactDom.findDOMNode(clock));
            var actualText = $el.find('.clock-text').text();
            expect(actualText).toBe('01:02');
        });
    });
    describe('formatSeconds', () => {
        it('should format seconds', () => {
            var clock = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Clock/>);
            var seconds = 615;
            var expected = '10:15';
            var actual = clock.formatSeconds(seconds);

        expect(actual).toBe(expected);
    });

    it('should format seconds when min/sec are less than 10', () => {
        var clock = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Clock/>);
        var seconds = 61;
        var expected = '01:01';
        var actual = clock.formatSeconds(seconds);

        expect(actual).toBe(expected);
        });
    });
});
```

wepackfile

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx'
  ],
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      Main: 'app/components/Main.jsx',
      Timer: 'app/components/Timer.jsx',
      Clock: 'app/components/Clock.jsx',
      Navigation: 'app/components/Navigation.jsx',
      Countdown: 'app/components/Countdown.jsx',
      applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "TimerApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple react app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Hyodo",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.9.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "expect": "^1.14.0",
    "foundation-sites": "6.2.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.6",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "script-loader": "^0.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}
```

Hope this help you or somebody. I got this problem after following a React course at Udemy. It is a little outdated but the test part was exactly what I was looking for. The problem is this kind of config.